# How to get value from linq query

Tags: c#, linq

i have the following linq query:

```
var dups = from row in DataTableFromObject.AsEnumerable()
                                 let maintx = row["Main Tx Number"].ToString()
                                 group row by maintx
                                     into DupMainTx
                                     where DupMainTx.Count() > 1
                                     select DupMainTx;
```

When I add a watch on dups, then open ResultsView, I will see entries [0] through [3] for each of the four rows with duplicate entries. If I expand [0] I see the value for Key which is the value i want. How can I access the key value for each row, which would be what is selected in select DupMainTx?
Thanks for your help-trying to teach myself linq.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dups` will be a collection of groupings, each of which has a `Key` property and can be enumerated:

```
foreach(var group in dups)
{
    // output the group key
    Console.WriteLine(group.Key);

    // enumerate the items in the group
    foreach(var row in group)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(row[{field}]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot for your help. That's what I was missing.

Answer (score 0):

You can get key and corresponding counts by adding `new{}` into `select` statement.

Replace:

```
select DupMainTx
```

with:

```
select new 
{
    dup = DupMainTx.Key,
    cnt = DupMainTx.Count(),
};
```

For further information, please see:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupby%28v=vs.90%29.aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb545971.aspx
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/LINQ-to-DataSets-Grouping-c62703ea